# Migration set per DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two DbContexts in one project which are both mapped to 2 different Schemas. I've set the MigrationHistoryTable for each DbContext to be stored in each corresponding schema.

```cs
services.AddDbContext<Context1>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(dataSource, sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", "Schema1");
        sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Context1))?.FullName);
    });
});

services.AddDbContext<Context2>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(dataSource, sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", "Schema2");
        sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Context2))?.FullName);
    });
});
```

I want to have 2 different Migration set for each dbcontext. The problem is when I add migration for any dbcontext (ex: `add-migration InitialMigration -c Context1`), it creates a subfolder under `Migrations` with the name of the db context and include both context changes.

Is there a way to have `Context1` migrations under `Migrations/Context1Db` and `Context2` migrations under `Migrations/Context2Db` **without creating two different migration assemblies**?